# R expression of the form 0 < \alpha < 1

Tags: r, expression, legend, legend-properties

I want to have a legend in an R plot involving expressions.
I did

```
legend(
  x = "topright",
  legend = c(expression(alpha == 0), expression(0 < alpha))
)
```

This works just fine. But if I replace the `0 < alpha` by `0 < alpha < 1` I get an error. Can someone tell me how to get an expression of the form `0 < \alpha < 1`? I didn't find it in the web.

Thanks a lot!
Maik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the second comparison in curly braces:

```
legend(
  x = "topright",
  legend = c(expression(alpha == 0), expression(0 < {alpha < 1}))
)
```